# Difference between these 2 declarations of structures in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, typedef, type-definition

I'm working on this project for college and they gave me a sample code to use while declaring a structure, the other one is how I declared it with the information on PowerPoints and other study material.

This is the code they gave me:

```
typedef struct sala local, *plocal;
struct sala {
    int id;
    int capacidade;
    int liga[3];
};
```

This is the code for another structure i did:

```
typedef struct pessoa {
    char id[15];
    int idade;
    char estado;
    int dias;
} pessoa;
```

Can anyone explain the difference to me ?

In my code editor "local" and "*local" appear in blue. (I use Netbeans).

Comment: Does Netbeans also make `int` and `double` appear in blue?

Comment: `typedef struct sala local, *local;` is invalid: `error: conflicting types for 'local'`

Comment: @FiddlingBits int and double appear in blue and local and *local appear in a light blue

Comment: @FiddlingBits int and double appear in blue and local and *local appear in a light blue

Comment: it is a very poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a typedef

Comment: @user3629249 why is that ? (The code with the pointer in typedef was givin to us by our professor)

Comment: It is very easy to miss read some code that contains a hidden pointer.  Much better to have `*` and/or `&` where the variable is used, rather than hidden in a typedef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef struct sala local, *local;
struct sala {
    int id;
    int capacidade;
    int liga[3];
};
```

is invalid because the name `local` is declared twice with different meanings: the first one as an alias for the type `struct sala` and the second one as an alias for the type `struct sala *`.

This is the difference between the first and the second typedef declarations.:)

As for the placement of typedef declaration then it may be placed either before a corresponding structure definition. together with structure definition or after  structure definition.

For example

```
typedef struct A A;
struct A
{
    int x;
};
```

or

```
typedef struct A
{
    int x;
} A;
```

or

```
struct A
{
    int x;
};

typedef struct A A;
```

An essence difference between these declarations is that if you want to refer to the defined structure inside its definition then in the second and third cases you have to use the type name `struct A` because the typedef name A was not yet declared.

For example

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    int x;
    Node *next;
};
```

but for example

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

Comment: So the " local " is like the " pessoa " at the bottom of the structure. Is that it ?

Comment: @MauroAbrantes Yes it  has the same meaning only in  the first typedef declaration the name local was redeclared that generates a compiler error.

Comment: i actually made a mistake, sorry ! its suppose to be " local, *plocal ". whats the difference between them ?

Comment: @MauroAbrantes In this case the first typedef is correct. Apart from an alias to the structure there is also declared an alias to the type pointer to the structure.

Comment: so i can use the *plocal to acess it globally in the program without having to use an auxiliary structure ?

Comment: @MauroAbrantes The declaration plocal p; is the same as the declaration struct sala *p;